# Failed MacbookAir boot Linux (Tails) - Kernel panic on boot

Tags: linux, boot, mac, kernel-panic, tails

I’ve an error with my MacBook Air (Retina, 13-inch, 2018), version 10.15.1

Boot ROM version : 1037.40.124.0.0 (iBridge: 17.16.11081.0.0,0)

I try to boot on Tails by a USB key and Apple adaptator Thunderbotl/USB

See the log after select Tails boot :

`(AE_ALREADY_EXISTS) (20190703/psparse-529
[   0.772994] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_PR.CPU0._PDC due to previous error
(AE_ALREADY_EXISTS) (20190703/psparse-529
[   0.773973] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS. SSDT 0xFFFF8E30353571C8 Table is a ready loaded (20190703/tbdata-520)
[   0.773979] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_PR.CPU1.APPT due to previous error
(AE_ALREADY_EXISTS) (20190703/psparse-529
[   0.773999] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_PR.CPU1.GCAP due to previous error
(AE_ALREADY_EXISTS) (20190703/psparse-529
[   0.774015] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_PR.CPU1._PDC due to previous error
(AE_ALREADY_EXISTS) (20190703/psparse-529
[   0774835] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.OCSP], AE_NOT_FOUND (20190703/psargs-330)
[   0.774850] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_PR.CPU2.GCAP due to previous error
(AE_NOT_FOUND) (20190703/psparse-529
[   0.774865] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_PR.CPU2._PDC due to previous error
(AE_NOT_FOUND) (20190703/psparse-529)
[   0775656] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.OCSP], AE_NOT_FOUND (20190703/psargs-330)
[   0.775671] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_PR.CPU3.GCAP due to previous error
(AE_NOT_FOUND) (20190703/psparse-529)
[   0.775685] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_PR.CPU3._PDC due to previous error
(AE_NOT_FOUND) (20190703/psparse-529)
[   3.710648] DMAR: Failed to find handle for ACPI object \_SB.PCI0.UA00
[   3.791278] Couldn’t get size: 0x8000000000000015 
[   3.791299] Kernel panic - not syncing: stack-protector: Kernel stack is corrupted in: get_cert_list+0x172/0x181
[   3.791333] CPU: 1 PID: 1 Comm: swapper/0 Tainted: G  W   5.3.0-trunk-amd64 #1 Debian 5.3.2-1 »exp1
[   3.791365] Hardware name: Apple Inc. MacBookAir8,1/Mac-827FAC58AFDFAZZ, BIOS 1037.40.124.0.0 (iBridge: 17.16.11081.0.0,0) 10/17/2019
[   3.791403] Call Trace:
[   3.791412]  dump_stack+0x5c/0x80
[   3.791423]  panic+0x101/0x2d7
[   3.791435]  ? printk+0x58/0x6f
[   3.791444]  ? get_cert_list+0x172/0x181
[   3.791483]  __stack_chk_fail+0x15/0x20
[   3.791494]  get_cert_list+0x172/0x181
[   3.791514] Kernel Offset: 0x12600000 from 0xffffffff!&000000 (relocation range: 0xffffffff80000000-0xffffffffbfffffff)
[   3.791550] —[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: stack-protector: Kernel stack is corrupted in: get_cert_list+0x172/0x181 ]—`

I installed Tails on the USB key by command line on my Mac with the dmg image, and also from parallels (use ISO to virtual machine of tails) : install the copy from tails installer to the USB key.
I’ve the same issue with these two installation methods.

Can you help me please ?

Thanks for your support

Comment: Have you tried `acpi=off` as a diagnosis helper?

Comment: Yes I tried with acpi=off in safe mode, I have the same kernel panic error